# Determine if sentences are similar

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of hundreds of fitness goals. Below is a subset.

1. "I'd like to lose 10 lbs."
2. "To run a mile under 6 minutes."
3. "To run a mile under 7 minutes."
4. "To get swimsuit ready and lose 5 pounds."
5. "Be able to run a mile is less than seven minutes."

How do I find matches of similar fitness goals? For example, #1 and #4 both want to lose weight and #3 and #5 both want to run a mile under 7 minutes. Also, #2, #3, and #5 all want to run faster. How do I efficiently search through this table of fitness goals to determine which goals are similar? The goals are stored in a mysql table. I'm looking for an implementation in PHP.

Comment: This is really too broad a problem for a SO question, but I'd ask - are these goals all user-defined?  It'd be much easier if you created templates which users could fill (eg "I want to do $x in $y"), is that feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one of two ways:

Inside PHP you can use [similar-text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function. This is however a pretty ordinary way of doing this.

The better approach is to use [Mysql's full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). The Problem is that you can't compare two rows inside the database, but rather a text string against the data in the table:

Example based on:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE articles (
    ->   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   title VARCHAR(200),
    ->   body TEXT,
    ->   FULLTEXT (title,body)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO articles (title,body) VALUES
    -> ('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
    -> ('How To Use MySQL Well','After you went through a ...'),
    -> ('Optimizing MySQL','In this tutorial we will show ...'),
    -> ('1001 MySQL Tricks','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
    -> ('MySQL vs. YourSQL','In the following database comparison ...'),
    -> ('MySQL Security','When configured properly, MySQL ...');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Tutorial')
    -> FROM articles;
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Tutorial') |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 |                        0.65545833110809 |
|  2 |                                       0 |
|  3 |                        0.66266459226608 |
|  4 |                                       0 |
|  5 |                                       0 |
|  6 |                                       0 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This will rank the results according to best match.

You could use this nicely to get a row from your database and then use this to find the best matched rows.

Answer (score 1):

Well you might flag some keywords like "weight", "lbs", "pounds" and can be checked by an admin later

Answer (score 0):

This is just  me poking at the dark, but you could have multiple boolean values.

```
runFaster=true;
loseWeight=true;
specificDistance=true; //Do they have a specific distance in mind?
```

and Some quantitative values:

```
weightLoss=3; //lbs
speedIncrease=1 //km/h
runDistance=7 //miles
```

something like that?

Comment: Have these as columns for each fitness goal. The more matches, the better!